Password failed with special Characters in Puppet
Open question, have anyone ever faced issue failing of login for password with special characters in puppet
for example : password postgres user - ]htXXXXUyzJ5]yj!C it's not accepting

12:58
~# pp
Info: Using environment 'nre_restore_script'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Notice: Requesting catalog from xxx:8141 (xxx5)
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Lookup of key 'lookup_options' failed: Unable to parse (/etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/hieradata-nodes-configuration/Linux/ops4ops/onezabbix/claranet/databases/rmp/preproduction/params.yaml): expected the node content, but found ']' while parsing a block node at line 74 column 23 (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/nre_restore_script/modules/stdlib/manifests/init.pp, line: 11, column: 3) on node XXXXX
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run


Here I have added what's on line 74 in param.yaml file :

Here is the classes defined, the password is .pgpass:


The messages presented do not describe a login failure.  They describe one of your Hiera data files being malformed, with the result that catalog building fails.  It is entirely possible that this is related to special characters appearing in what is supposed to be a value within that file, but you haven't given us anything to go on to confirm that hypothesis or suggest a fix.

The error mentions .../params.yaml (line 74) and .../init.pp (line 11). Why not show them?

@WalterA Here i have updated question with line 74 which is commented but when i uncomment it throws error.

Not tested, but try putting them in double quotes.
Use quotes in YAML if your value includes special characters. For example, these special characters may require quotes: {, }, [, ], ,, &, :, *, #, ?, |. -, <. >, =, !, %, @, .

With the double quotes it is solved, but we are using auto password fetch mechanism

So what, @JYOTIRAJAI? When you record the password in your Hiera data, you must do so in a manner consistent with the expected YAML format of the data file.  That that may require quotes to be added, or other, similar processing is par for the course in this kind of activity.  It should not be difficult to understand that failing to do that correctly renders the file invalid, and that in that case, Puppet rejects the file.  "Make Puppet read the file even though it is invalid" is not a plausible request.

The problem is that the first character, the [ and ']' are used for an array.
With a different first character, it should work.
This is not a problem of puppet, these are restrictions/requirements of json.
I faced failing logins in different tools when the password had special characters in it. In all these cases, it was a problem how I processed the string with the special characters.
Examples:
First, I create the script pwcheck.sh that wants the password My * [secret] (not starting with a [ or ], an easy case):
read -p "Password: " password
if [[ $password == 'My * [secret]' ]]; then
  echo "Correct"
else
  echo "Wrong"
fi

Using echo with and without quotes:
$ echo 'My * [secret]' | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct
$ echo My * [secret] | ./pwcheck.sh
Wrong

Using an ini-file that is sourced
$ echo 'pw="My * [secret]"' > pw.ini; source pw.ini; echo "$pw" | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct
$ unset pw
$ echo 'pw=My * [secret]' > pw.ini; source pw.ini; echo "$pw" | ./pwcheck.sh
$(echo 444): command not found
Wrong

When you have a yaml file, different tools read the data as expected:
$ printf '%s\n' 'Demo:' '  password: My * [secret]' > pw.yaml
$ cat pw.yaml
Demo:
  password: My * [secret]
$ perl -MYAML -le 'print YAML::LoadFile(shift)->{Demo}{password}' pw.yaml | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct
$ ruby -r yaml -e 'puts YAML.load_file(ARGV[0])["Demo"]["password"]' pw.yaml | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct
$ yq -r .Demo.password pw.yaml | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct

And with the puppet file pw.pp:
$myhash = parseyaml(file('/full/path/to/pw.yaml'))
$pw=$myhash['Demo']['password']
notice("pw=[$pw]")

I need sed to remove colour codes from the output:
$ sudo puppet apply --modulepath /etc/puppet/code/modules pw.pp 2>/dev/null |
    sed -En 's/.*pw=\[(.*)\].*/\1/p' | ./pwcheck.sh
Correct

When we use the same tools for a different yaml file, starting with a '[', it goes wrong:
$ cat pw.yaml
Demo:
  password: [My * [secret]]

$ perl -MYAML -le 'print YAML::LoadFile(shift)->{Demo}{password}' pw.yaml
YAML Error: Can't parse inline sequence
   Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_INLINE_SEQUENCE
   Line: 2
   Document: 1
 at /home/walter/perl5/lib/perl5/YAML/Loader.pm line 551.

$ ruby -r yaml -e 'puts YAML.load_file(ARGV[0])["Demo"]["password"]' pw.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        6: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:497:in `load_file'
        5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:497:in `open'
        4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:498:in `block in load_file'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:263:in `load'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:350:in `parse'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse_stream'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse': (pw.yaml): did not find expected ',' or ']' while parsing a flow sequence at line 2 column 13 (Psych::SyntaxError)

$ yq -r .Demo.password pw.yaml
Error: bad file 'pw.yaml': yaml: line 1: did not find expected ',' or ']'

$ sudo puppet apply --modulepath /etc/puppet/code/modules pw.pp
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, (<unknown>): did not find expected ',' or ']' while parsing a flow sequence at line 2 column 13 (file: .../pw.pp, line: 1, column: 11) on node ****

Generating a yaml including quotes is the best way.
Work-around: sed -Ei 's/(superuser_password: )(.*)/\1"\2"/' params.pp

I have attached a snapshot of puppet classes, how can I modify in that ?

You are attaching additional questions. First the question was about params.yaml and now .pgpass. I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but you might want to use exec for creating an improved .pgpass.pp file. Or make a rule for your password that it can not start with a [.

@JYOTIRAJAI, you cannot fix the problem in your Puppet classes.  I keep telling you: you need to fix the data.

Have  you ever come around hashing of password, just giving a thought if it can help the situation.

@JYOTIRAJAI, you could conceivably encode the password in a way that avoids special characters appearing (maybe base-64, for example) and then decode that in your manifests.  You cannot use hashing per se, however, because you need to be able to get the actual password, whereas hashing is one-way.  But this is still about the data first.  If you have enough control over the data to substitute a base-64 encoded version, then you should also have enough to just ensure a properly quoted and escaped version in the first place, leaving no special handling to perform in your manifests.
